# Nodejs "Unexpected token ." when creating object

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have tried to search my problem but I couldn't even know how to ask it. I looked similar questions but I couldn't find anything. So here is my problem.

I have two js files. First one is **constant.js** which keeps HTTP field names. Here is the code snippet of it

```
module.exports = {
    USERNAME: 'username'
};
```

The second file is **test.js** and I would like to create some object inside of this file. While creating an object I would like to use constant.js file property names as shown in below:

```
var constant = require('./constant');

var x = {
    constant.USERNAME: "test"
};

console.log(x);
```

When i execute **test.js** I expected to see `{ username: 'test' }` in the console but I got this following error:

```
constant.USERNAME: "test"
        ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token .
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:73:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:443:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
    at startup (node.js:129:16)
    at node.js:814:3
```

I don't know why is it happening. Why can't I create my object? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**NOTE:** Both files are on the same folder. There is no module export error. When I try to `console.log(constant)` it works well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JS object literals (`x = { ... }`) consist of `name: value` pairs, where the `name` is a literal (and JS does not allow `.` in it), and you cannot use another variable here. To achieve what I think you want to achieve, I would do:

```
x = {};
x[constant.USERNAME] = "test";
```

Answer (score 3):

In case of literal object notation, the property names are not evaluated. Furthermore, `constant.USERNAME` is an invalid property name.

If you want to use the value of `constant.USERNAME` as the property name, you need to use the "array notation", like this:

```
var x = {};
x[constant.USERNAME] = 'test';
```

Answer (score 2):

You should either use [new syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names) from ECMAScript 2015 (supported in nodejs 4 and newer):

```
var x = {
    [constant.USERNAME]: "test"
};
```

or stick with plain old:

```
var x = {};
x[constant.USERNAME] = "test";
```